# sentimentr 0 instead of NA

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

Function sentiment from 'sentimentr' package returns 0 for NAs, however, I need NAs.

I'm using 'sentimentr' package for the Sentiment Analysis on a large dataset. Some values are, of course, missing. However, for NAs the function 'sentiment' returns 0. The problem is that sometimes sentiment is indeed 0, but sometimes is just NA. I need to differentiate for future analysis. I've tried to use na.rm = TRUE and also na.action=NULL, but this did not work. I still get an output with 0s.

```
  #so first I split the text into sentences
  mytext <- get_sentences(Hotels$H1_content, na.rm = TRUE)
  #then I want the function to classify sentiment
  newdata <- sentiment(mytext, na.rm = TRUE)
  newdata <- sentiment(mytext, na.action=NULL)
  head(newdata$sentiment)
  [1] 0.37500000 0.06123724 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Ideally, I would like NA to stay NA after the sentiment analysis and if the sentiment is really 0, then 0. It should be easy, but it's not working for me. I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Have a look at `?sentiment`. It describes the `missing_value` parameter like so: `missing_value: 
A value to replace NA/NaN with. Use NULL to retain missing values.` By default, `missing_value` is set to zero.

Comment: @Lyngbakr thank you very much, it worked!